# jQuery - run perl script (all standalone)

Tags: javascript, jquery, perl

I have script Perl and for the moment this script is called with a simple batch file.

To make this interface more attractive, I'm looking for a language for create a GUI.

My first idea is to use jQuery/jQuery UI.
Before starting to learn, I want to know if is it possible to run a script perl with jQuery(UI).

**fyi, I haven't Web server all code is standalone.**

Of course, I'm interested if you have an idea for another language.

Thank's for your help.

Comment: FYI you can create GUI application using perl too

Comment: You do realize that jQuery is JavaScript, right? and that creating a GUI can be done using Perl, or Python, or PHP, or C... just check [the GTK language bindings](http://www.gtk.org/language-bindings.php)

Answer (score 1):

jQuery is a JavaScript library for use in web pages. The primary way for JavaScript in a web page to interact with a Perl program is through HTTP (typically by using the XMLHttpRequest object to make an HTTP request). The HTTP server is responsible for running the Perl code (e.g. through PSGI, FastCGI, mod_perl, CGI or having a server written in Perl in the first place).

Without a web server, it isn't possible for a typical environment.

(There are exceptions, but they usually involve the browser being driven by Perl using something like Selenium).